# progress Bar not working from Jframe in java

Tags: java, swing

when I am trying to call method updateProgressBar method when the Jbutton is clicked but the progress is not displayed only the blank dialogue Box appear till the value reached 100%.

```
      following is the method from class ProgressBar which will display Jdialogue box with progress bar.



                public void updateProgressBar(int i)
                {

                    pb.setString("Processing " + i + "%");
                    pb.setValue(i);



                        try
                        {
                         Thread.sleep(100);
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                }


following is how it is called from Jframe.
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
         // TODO add your handling code here:

 ProgressBar pd=new ProgressBar();

  int i=1,j=100;
  pd.setVisible(true);
  while (i<=50)
  {
  pd.updateProgressBar(i);
  i++;
  }
  pd.dispose();


    }
```

Comment: You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: I couldnot get you !

Comment: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)